# C++ malloc runtime exception

Tags: c++, gcc, cross-compiling

So yes this is a question about

```
mallocErroc: malloc.c:3096: sYSMALLOc: Assertion `(old_top == (((mbinptr) (((char *) &((av)->bins[((1) - 1) * 2])) - __builtin_offsetof
 (struct malloc_chunk, fd)))) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= (unsigned long)((((__builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, 
fd_nextsize))+((2 * (sizeof(size_t))) - 1)) & ~((2 * (sizeof(size_t))) - 1))) && ((old_top)->size & 0x1) && ((unsigned long)old_end & pagemask) == 
0)' failed
```

but with a twist I hope someone can shed some light on.  Here's the code I have with the problem happening:

```
#include <map>

class blah {
    public:
        blah();
    private:
        std::map<int, int> iMap;
        std::map<const char *, std::string> sMap;
};

blah::blah()
{
    iMap[0] = 10;
    sMap["Test"] = std::string("this is a test");
}
```

I'm using Cross GCC 9 to build the above for both X86 and ARM machines running linux (built from scratch via yocto).  The above code works without issue on the X86 machine but on the ARM machine I get the malloc assertion when the `sMap["Test"] = std::string("this is a test")` line is executed.  Anyone have any thoughts.  Is this maybe an ARM c++ library implementation issue or maybe gcc?  The two cross development environments are built from the same source set.  If I remove the line of code mentioned everything works on the ARM machine.

Comment: I smell a heap corruption. Try running with an address sanitizer and/or valgrind. If it doesn't help, make a [mcve].

Comment: Unrelated: Even if it "works" on the x86 machine you can't be sure that the `const char*` you store in the `map` can later be found by using `sMap["Test"]`. If they _are_ the same it's because of an optimization (that isn't mandated by the standard).

Comment: *"but with a twist"* -- this brings two questions to my mind. **1)** What is the twist? **2)** What is the original *(supposedly well-known or ubiquitous?)* situation that the twist is on? It's not like that's an error I see every day (or even recall encountering specifically). Maybe others recognize the error instantly, but do you want to restrict your audience? Context is good.

Comment: `std::map<const char *, std::string> sMap;` -- This is a code smell, and possibly a bug.  Why not make the key a `std::string`?  As mentioned, if your compiler has a mode where it doesn't "merge duplicate strings", your code will be broken at runtime when attempting to search for the key.

Comment: The twist is that the code works on X86 but but not ARM.

Answer (score 0):

To understand what is going on here, let's rewrite the code like:

```
blah::blah()
{
    // ...
    const char* p = "Test"; // (1)
    sMap[p] = std::string("this is a test"); // (2)
}
```

(1) - creates a variable in local scope (on stack) with automatic storage duration
(2) - inserts a *key-value* pair (constructed in-place; assume *key* doesn't exists in the map) into the map: the value of `p` is copied to *key* and the value of temporary `std::string` is copied (actually move-constructed) to *value*.
When execution goes out of constructor scope, the storage for the *key* object no longer exists. So the copied pointer value holds an address of "nowhere", while the *value* is still valid as well-constucted.

Comment: Ok thanks.  I kind of thought it was a "scoping" issue but was at a loss to understand why it worked when compiled for X86 but not for ARM.  So, as I understand it, I just got lucky with it working on X86, correct?

Comment: Right. In fact, it is undefined behavior, so everything can happen, even "lucky" run.

Comment: If this is really a "scoping" issue shouldn't either valgrind or asan be able to detect it?  Neither valgrind memcheck nor asan detect any issues with the X86 version.  I don't have access to the ARM version today so I don't know if I get different results on that platform.

Comment: Nevermind, I found some info online detailing why valgrind or any other tool can't really detect scoping issues.

Comment: Compilers can produse code placing string literal into ro data section, and generate code to further access it. Let's add the simple dtor `~blah() { cout << sMap["Test"]; }`. In that case it can print *"this is a test"*. To see it is the scope issue, replace  `const char* p = ...` with `char p[] = ...` so literal is really on stack (ensure build optimisations are off). Will it print the string?

Comment: If I use __sMap["Test"] = "This is a test"__ or __const char *p = "Test"__ with __sMap[p] = "This is a test"__ both the key and value are printed in the dtor.  If I use __const p[] = "Test"__ and __sMap[p] = "This is a test"__ asan catches it during compile.  If I turn off asan, it is not caught during compile but runtime doesn't work.  Optimizer is off via __-O0__ for all three cases.  Will try same on ARM machine tomorrow.  At this point I'm just trying to find out if there is a compiler option or something that will reliably warn about this sort of thing.

Comment: With both of the first two cases the key __"Test"__ is placed in the rodata section with or without optimization enabled.  Wouldn't that mean a pointer to that string would be valid no matter what?  Oh forgot to mention I misstated, asan doesn't catch at compile time but does so at runtime.

Comment: "No matter what" outside ctor the pointer is not valid. Accessing it is UB.

Comment: I realize the pointer in the ctor itself can not be valid outside of the ctor but a new pointer to the rodata string created outside of the ctor will be.  If I add __const char *p = "Test"__ in the dtor and I print the value of the pointer in the ctor and the value of the one in the dtor, they are identical and both print __"Test"__ when I print what they point to.  I feel like there is something I am missing here.

Comment: You are trying to guess the reason why specific compiler of specific version for specific arch/os generated code like that for UB... What's the goal?

Comment: The goal is to find out if there is a compiler or other tool option that will at least warn of the situation instead of just producing an executable that will fail.  I already figured out how to fix the issue regardless of which compiler/os/architecture the code is used on.  I just was hoping to see if there was a warning (I have Wall enabled) I could enable that would let me know when there are those sorts of issues.  I'm working with thousands of lines of someone else's code and it'd be nice to be able to trust that the compiled code is good.  Don't confuse "good" with bug free.